# need to consider possible combinations for a binary choice in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, counting

I want to construct an 2^n*n matrix to evaluate all possible decision vectors for a binary decision by n agents.

So, N people choose between {0,1} and their choices form a decision vector, e.g [1,1,0,1,0.....]. I want a matrix consisting of all the possible decision vectors.

I tried using `repmat` to replicate {0,1} n times and then `allcomb`, but that didn't work. (maybe I did it wrong.)

I also read somewhere that i would be able to use `A = (dec2bin(0:(2^n)-1));` and indeed, i did get something that resembled what i was after, however, the rest of my program(for the actual analysis portion of my research) gave rubbish results.

I wrote a code in matlab that does this (and mode) for 5 people but I just nested 5 loops. I would like to extend this. Any help is appreciated.

current code is

```
A= zeros (2^n,n); %creates blank strategy space 

x=0; % x is an iteration counting term and should be = 2^n if code runs correctly
for i=0:1

for j=0:1

    for k=0:1


        for l=0:1

            for m=0:1
               x=x+1;
               v1=i;
               v2=j;
               v3=k;
               v4=l;
               v5=m;
               A(x,:)=[v1 v2 v3 v4 v5]; % at termination this loop should generate an exhaustive list of all possible strategy profiles
            end
        end
    end
end
end
x;
```

I only started using MATLAB yesterday, so i imagine this is quite bad...

Comment: Please post your current code! :)

Comment: How is using `dec2bin` rubbish? It reproduces what you wrote in your code exactly.

Comment: Maybe the rest of the code fails because `-'0'` is missing after `dec2bin`

Comment: @LuisMendo - I suspect you're right!

Comment: @rayryeng Nice answer, BTW!

Comment: @LuisMendo - Gracias :D.  The subtraction of `'0'` I learned from you!

Comment: @rayryeng Haha. Well, I also learned it here! :-)

Comment: the `-0` was exactly the problem. Thanks you for that! @rayryeng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, given `n` bits, you want to enumerate all possible decimal values into their binary equivalent from 0 up to `2^n-1`.  That can be done with a call to [`dec2bin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) and converting to a numerical array:

```
n = 5;
A = dec2bin(0:2^n-1, n) - '0';
```

I provided a vector from 0 up to `2^n-1` in steps of 1 and allow `dec2bin` to convert each one of those decimal values into its binary form that has `n` digits.

The subtraction with `'0'` is important as `dec2bin` originally produces an array of characters where each row is a sequence of binary digits but are characters instead.  If you want to convert the character array into numerical, bear in mind that the characters are represented in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and so subtracting with the ASCII code of the digit 0 will get you down to the actual values of 0 and 1.

Using `n=5`, we get this (which is the same as what your code produces):

```
A =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0     1
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     1     1     1
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     1
     0     1     0     1     0
     0     1     0     1     1
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     1
     1     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     1     0
     1     0     0     1     1
     1     0     1     0     0
     1     0     1     0     1
     1     0     1     1     0
     1     0     1     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     1
     1     1     0     1     0
     1     1     0     1     1
     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     0     1
     1     1     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: @SikandarSinghSoin - My pleasure.  Good luck!